# how to add object at specific index and also remove another object from NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

hello friends i'm new in ios development.
i want to add object at specified index for that i code here.

```
arrNotificationTime = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arrNotificationView.count];

for (int i=0; i<arrNotificationView.count; i++)
{
    [arrNotificationTime addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
NSLog(@"Time count == %d",[arrNotificationTime count]);
[arrNotificationTime replaceObjectAtIndex:btnNotificationTime.tag withObject:btnNotificationTime.titleLabel.text];
```

and it work perfectly but i also want to remove another or the same object from this array or also print this array is not work for that i code here.

```
NSLog(@"arrNotificationTime == %@",arrNotificationTime);
[arrNotificationTime removeObjectAtIndex:[btn tag]];
```

when i nslog the array it will crash the application.
The error report is.

```
2014-05-13 17:52:09.973 TOPDesign[1057:11303] arrNotificationTime count = 0
2014-05-13 17:52:09.974 TOPDesign[1057:11303] arrNotificationTime == (
)
2014-05-13 17:52:09.975 TOPDesign[1057:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x15ae012 0x12bbe7e 0x15501c4 0xc6ec 0x12cf705 0x2032c0 0x203258 0x2c4021 0x2c457f 0x2c36e8 0x4c71d3 0x1576afe 0x1576a3d 0x15547c2 0x1553f44 0x1553e1b 0x260f7e3 0x260f668 0x1ffffc 0x2592 0x24c5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: From Nslog your `array` looks `empty` and you are trying to `remove` that object which `doesnt exist` in your array.

Comment: Thank you @ChinttuRoxeNRamani now i understand the problem and thank you for sharing knowledge with me and others.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA check this link for more information https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDAJBB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove any object in empty array. so it crashes.

you must use like this

```
 [arrNotificationTime count] is total count of your array
```

suppose you have 10 items

you btn tag should be within 0 to 9. if you access the 11th item then it will crash. to avoid it. you must use like this

```
if([arrNotificationTime count]>[btn tag]){


    [arrNotificationTime removeObjectAtIndex:[btn tag]];


}
```

Comment: can you please give me some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is for adding object in specific index in array.

```
[YourArray insertObject:@"" atIndex:0];
```

This is for remove object at specific object.

```
[YourArray removeObjectAtIndex:5];
```

Hope this code is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `arrNotificationTime`  array no object and you remove the object.so app is crashed.